# DSolve Error 3D Navier Stokes (z,r,t)

Tags: differential-equations, computational-geometry, nonlinear, fluid-dynamics

I am essentially wanting to solve Navier Stokes in the [z,r,t] dimensions (2D+Unsteady Flow) for pressure driven flow.  However, I keep getting an error I am unable to resolve in my Dsolve such as:

**"To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable 
in u[z,r,t] should literally match the independent variables. "**

```
R = .5;
rc = .47;
\[Mu] = 1;
\[Rho] = 1;

fz = {u[z, r, t]*D[u[z, r, t], z] - \[Mu]*D[u[z, r, t], z, z] + 
    D[P[z], z] == \[Mu]*(1/r*D[r*D[u[z, r, t], r], r]) - 
    v[z, r, t]*D[u[z, r, t], r] - \[Rho]*D[u[z, r, t], t]}

fr = {\[Rho]*(D[v[z, r, t], t] + v*D[v[z, r, t], r] + 
      u[z, r, t]*D[v[z, r, t], z]) == \[Mu]*(1/r*
       D[r*D[v[z, r, t], r], r] - v[z, r, t]/r^2 + D[v[z, r, t], z])}
contEqu = {D[u[z, r, t], z] == -1/r*D[r*v[z, r, t], r]};


eq = {fz, fr}  

bcs = {u[1, R, t] == 0, v[1, R, t] == 0, u[1, rc, t] == 0, 
  v[1, rc, t] == 0, u[0, rc, t] == 0, v[0, rc, t] == 0, 
  u[0, R, t] == 0, u[z, r, 0] == newIC[z]}  

**DSolve[{eq}, {u[z, r, t], v[z, r, t]}, {z, 0, 5}, {r, rc, R}, {t, 0, 
  1}]**
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: 1) Your `DSolve` syntax incorrect; you seem to be using syntax that would be more appropriate for `NDSolve`. 2) your function `v` appears once without arguments in `fr`: it should probably appear as `v[z, r, t]` instead. Maybe you could start from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that your equations can be solved with `DSolve`, because they are nonlinear.  Instead use, `NDSolve`  To do so, `P[z]` and `newIC[z]` must be defined.  For now, I set them to zero.  Also, boundary conditions must be defined at surfaces, not corners, which I also fixed.  Finally, there was one occurrence of `v` without arguments in `fr`, which I fixed.  With these changes,

```
R = .5; rc = .47; μ = 1; ρ = 1;

fz = u[z, r, t]*D[u[z, r, t], z] - μ*D[u[z, r, t], z, z] == 
    μ*(1/r*D[r*D[u[z, r, t], r], r]) - v[z, r, t]*D[u[z, r, t], r] - ρ*D[u[z, r, t], t];
fr = ρ*(D[v[z, r, t], t] + v[z, r, t]*D[v[z, r, t], r] + u[z, r, t]*D[v[z, r, t], z]) == 
    μ*(1/r*D[r*D[v[z, r, t], r], r] - v[z, r, t]/r^2 + D[v[z, r, t], z]);
contEqu = D[u[z, r, t], z] == -1/r*D[r*v[z, r, t], r];
eq = {fz, fr}  

bcs = {u[z, R, t] == 0, v[z, R, t] == 0, u[z, rc, t] == 0, v[z, rc, t] == 0, 
       u[0, r, t] == 0, v[0, r, t] == 0, u[5, r, t] == 0, v[5, r, t] == 0, 
       u[z, r, 0] == 1, v[z, r, 0] == 1} 

{su, sv} = NDSolveValue[{eq, bcs}, {u, v}, {z, 0, 5}, {r, rc, R}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

produces

```
Plot3D[su[z, r, 1], {z, 0, 5}, {r, rc, R}, AxesLabel -> {z, r, u}]
```

[image]

Define your two functions and provide alternative boundary conditions for more interesting results.

Comment: Thank you for the direction bbgodfrey, that is what I needed to get off the ground.

Comment: @AStone  Glad I could help.  By the way, my sample answer generates a warning message that boundary conditions are incompatible.  This happens at corners, where one boundary might have a value of one and the other of zero, for instance.  Usually, not a problem but sometimes it is.  Try to avoid this with your real boundary conditions.  Thanks for accepting the answer.